# Config transform error setting up Episerver 9 Commerce project

Tags: episerver

I am following instructions to set up a new `Episerver 9` commerce site.

I've followed the instructions at: http://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Installation-Instructions/installing-episerver/#Commerce

When I install NuGet package `EpiServer.CommerceManager` I get the following error:

> An error occurred while applying transformation to 'web.config' in
>   project 'WebCommerceApplication' No element in the source document
>   matches '/configuration/system.serviceModel/services'

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a transform for an element that's missing in `web.config`.

Make sure you have an element like...

```
<configuration>
   <system.serviceModel>
      <services />
   <system.serviceModel>
<configuration>
```

...in your `web.config`.

Comment: It is also important that the config has a `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` on the first line